# Matching a value of HashMap to values in a HashSet

Tags: java, string, set

I am trying to match the values of the key in the contextMap to a set of string. I know there is a clear match but despite that I get an empty map in my output. Is it correct to use the contains() method in this case?

The context map contents look like:

> [Rhode Island ]=[leftWords: [fellow], rightWords: [solution,
>   provider]]

And the roleContexts set looks like :

> [recent performance, has earned , holdings in , senior vice president
>   of, solution provider , pharmaceuticals, has launched ]

Here the word solution provider should be a match, thus the key Rhode Island should by put in the output map with he corresponding role (Location in this case).

```
for(Entry<Set<String>, Set<Words>> entry : contextMap.entrySet()) {

         for (String key : entry.getKey()){

             for (Words value : entry.getValue()) {

                for(SemanticRole role : roleContextsMap.keySet())
                {   

                    Set<String> roleContexts = roleContextsMap.get(role);

                    if(roleContexts.contains(value.getLeftWords().toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]","").replaceAll(","," ").toLowerCase()) 
                            || roleContexts.contains(value.getRightWords().toString().toString().replaceAll("\\[|\\]","").replaceAll(","," ").toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        Set<String> roleStrings = roleStringsMap.containsKey(role) 
                                ? roleStringsMap.get(role) : new HashSet<String>();
                        roleStrings.add(key);
                        roleStringsMap.put(role, roleStrings);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Do you want to add `roleStringsMap.get(role)` to `roleStrings`? That's not what you do. You have to change your ternary if in a "normal" if-else and use `roleStrings.add()`.

Comment: @IQV Thanks. I'll look into this. However,the code doesn't even go inside the if statement. So I am guessing there is an issue in the way I am matching.